# Facebook Analytics Push Campaigns on iOS - delivered but not displayed

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-analytics

[event debuging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2bZR.png)

As the picture shows, apns messages were delivered. But the client didn't receive any notification. After testing, the client can receive notifications created by our own server.
And why the app version and device os are unknown for "delivered" log?
Thank you for answering

Answer (score 0):

How did you send the notification to the device? the picture shows the event debugging log which suggest this device has a push token (good!).
Did you create a push campaign targeting that device?
Have you verified that device is included in the targeting segment?

Comment: Sure. Verified. Today, it works finally, but I did't change anything. It is really confusing. And I opened my app through the notification, but the number of opened was zero. Do you have any idea? FBSDKAppEvents.logPushNotificationOpen(userInfo)

Comment: `FBSDKAppEvents.logPushNotificationOpen(userInfo)`
I have wrote this at  
`func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any]) `
and 
`func application(_ application: UIApplication, handleActionWithIdentifier identifier: String?, forRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void)`